# I want to calculate occurence of data over a range (period of 10) in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have data in numeric form so I want to calculate occurrence of data in a range (period of 10). I have created a Python script. The
original script is very long because of large dataset so I am putting here a sample code.
In the actual code `malware_opcd_frq` list size is approx 19000 and bins list `[0,11,21,31...........13991,14000]`

**opcode_frequency.py**

```
import numpy as np
malware_opcd_frq = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,19,25,26,28,29,35,41,43,43,49,54,57,60,71,78,79,81,81,92,99,99,105,107,109,119,129,134,142,142,145,146,150,158,166,166,171,172,173,180,183,186,187,191,191,192,192,192,192,192,192,192,192,192,192,192,192,192,192,192,192,192,192,195,198,199,203,209,209,217,217,220,220,225,226,226,226,226,226,226,226,226,226,226,226,228,234,234,235,236,236,236,237,237,239,240,241,241,243,244,244,245,245,245,245,246,247,248,250,253,256,257,258,259,259,260,262,264,264,267,267,267,269,270,270,272,273,274,275,278,279,284,295,295,300])
frq = np.histogram(malware_opcd_frq, bins= [0,11,21,31,41,51,61,71,81,91,101,111,121,131,141,151,161,171,181,191,201,211,221,231,241,251,261,271,281,291,300])
print frq
```

so after execution of the actual code which I have gives output like this

```
(array([29,  1,  4, ...,  5,  9,  7]), array([    0,    11,    21, ..., 13981, 13991, 14000]))
```

In the above output but I need full output — but I'm not getting it.  Please explain what I need to do.

Comment: What do you mean by "i need full output?"

Answer (score 0):

The "..." that you see are just a way to tell you that the variable is very big. Therefore you see just a small part of your variable.

frq is a tuple, where frq[0] are the amount of values in each bin and frq[1] are the bins that you use.

You can make the plot of all your data with:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(frq[1][1::],frq[0])
```